# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'And' stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
USE [productDb]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_ProcName]
    @Name VARCHAR(100),
    @PDate NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
    @City VARCHAR(100),
    @Birthday VARCHAR(100)
AS 
BEGIN
    IF (@Name = '')
       IF @Birthday = -1
       BEGIN
           SET @PDate = And ProductDate >= '08/04/1883'
       END
       ELSE 
       BEGIN
           SET @PDate = And ProductDate <= '08/04/1883'
       END
   ELSE
   BEGIN
       SELECT * FROM Product
   END
END
```

I get these errors:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure usp_ProcName, Line 18
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'And'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure usp_ProcName, Line 22
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'And'.

Comment: Hint:  `@PDate` is a string, so you need string operators.

Comment: The statement @PDate = And ProductDate >= '08/04/1883' looks weird...

Comment: @PetroK beyond weird, it is flat out invalid. But there is something very wrong with the code here in general.

Comment: `@PDate` will contain a string. Not *arbitrary fragments of a complete SQL query that the engine will treat as such*. There's no means to store a fragment of an SQL statement, nor a means to "compose" such fragments into a whole statement. (outside of using strings throughout and forcing a separate parse/compile/execute stage which I try to avoid).

Comment: You should ask a question about how to achieve your end goal. Your current approach is way off track

Comment: What is this stored procedure supposed to achieve? What is `@PDate` supposed to end up containing?

Comment: The only case here that makes sense is that @PDate is an entire SQL query, and you are attempting to add a conditional value onto the end of the query while executing it. This is not valid T-SQL as is. Instead, you can use `SET @PDate = @PDate + ' AND ProductDate >= ''08/04/1883'''`. NOTE: You will still need to execute the query separately with `EXEC (@PDate)`. If @PDate is not an SQL query string, then you can ignore this answer.

Comment: Side/Snide note - please realise that prefixing object names in SQL Server with something indicating their type is counterproductive. There is only one case where names *can* be ambiguous in the T-SQL syntax and it's deliberate (views vs tables). Anywhere else, from syntax, you *know* the object type without these "helpful" prefixes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems in your stored procedure:

1. Using `SET` operator incorrectly. It is an error
2. As Sean Lange commented out there is an Implicit conversion from `datetime` to `varchar(max)`. This approach allows you to change formats if it is required, or do date math.

Let's see the first error more precisely:
The `SET` operator is used to assign data. You write incorrect statements in `SET`:

```
set @PDate = And ProductDate >= '08/04/1883'
    End
    Else
    Begin
        set @PDate = And ProductDate <= '08/04/1883'
```

You should set data in SET operator. For example:

```
Begin
    set @PDate = GETDATE()
End
Else
    Begin
        set @PDate = GETDATE()
    end
```

And the second problem is implicit conversion from `datetime` to `varchar(max)`. It can be fixed by using correct data type. So this approach allows you to change formats if it is required, or do date math:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_ProcName]
 @Name          VARCHAR(100) 
, @PDate         DateTime = NULL
, @City          VARCHAR(100) 
, @Birthday      VARCHAR(100) 
AS 
IF (@Name='')
If @Birthday=-1
Begin
    set @PDate = GETDATE()
End
Else
    Begin
        set @PDate = GETDATE()
    end
```

Comment: But @PDate is varchar(max) not a datetime datatype. The implicit conversion from datetime to varchar(max) is highly unlikely what the OP really wants.

Comment: @SeanLange Thanks for your correct comment. I've edited my answer using your comments. Thanks.